# unable to delete git branch due to "renamed branch"

Tags: github, branch, github-enterprise

I've scoured several different posts but there doesn't appear to be any that match with this exact issue of an "apparent" branch renaming occurring but nothing seeming to line up.

Essentially, I've been trying to delete a remote branch off of an enterprise git version but I've been getting rejected and I was wondering if there was any additional steps I can try out?

here is the following CLI information:

```
 | => git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/releases/v1.7.2_log4j2
(base) 
| ~/Documents/<repo> @ (user) 
| => git push origin -d releases/v1.7.2_log4j2
To https://github.<company>.com/<org>/<repo>.git
 ! [remote rejected] releases/v1.7.2_log4j2 (branch releases/v1.7.2_log4j2 is being renamed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.<company>.com/<org>/<repo>.git'
```

My git version: 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128).

EDIT: there are no branch protection rules that apply to this branch and I have tried the command in the suggestions of `git push -d origin releases<1.7.2_log4j2` with the same result

Comment: GitHub (but not base Git) systems, including GitHub Enterprise, add this sort of "branch protection" feature. It's controlled through the web interface: you must log in to the server via the web interface to do things to such branches.

Comment: @torek, there are no branch protection rules that apply to this release branch :(

Comment: I see from other replies that this appears to be a GitHub bug. I wonder what causes that flag to get set...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a github issue. There is a [github-community thread](https://github.community/t/python-cpython-zombie-master-branch/206066) where someone got the exact same message and it turned out to be a flag that was set within the github system that marked the branch as being renamed at the moment. They had to ask the github-support to clear that flag and then were able to delete the branch.

Comment: this is exactly my issue -- great find! I'll make a report and see about getting it deleted, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this fixed your problem you can consider setting this answer to "accepted" to let others know it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your parameters backwards. Try

```
git push -d origin releases/v1.7.2_log4j2
```

Comment: it works the same either way. Here's the result of your suggestion for reference:
```
git push -d origin releases/v1.7.2_log4j2
To https://github.<company>.com/<org>/<repo>.git
 ! [remote rejected] releases/v1.7.2_log4j2 (branch releases/v1.7.2_log4j2 is being renamed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.<company>.com/<org>/<repo>.git'
```

Comment: OK, that is strange.